# What are conditions for Tarski's fixed point theorem so that greatest and least fixed points are not the same?

Tags: fixed-point-theorems, lattice-orders

Tarski's fixed point theorem claims that for any monotone function on a complete lattice there are least and greatest fixed points (or more generally, that the set of fixed points is a complete lattice).

Under what conditions can one show that the greatest fixed point and the least fixed points are not the same? (i.e. that the complete lattice of fixed points is of size larger than 1.)